# Will adding a second Gateway on Windows 7 cause automatic load balancing

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

In the advanced tab on my IPv4 TCP/IP settings dialogue box, I have noticed that I can add a second default gateway.

We have two gateways on the network, so the ability to add a second one appeals to me. What happens to my internet traffic once I add the second gateway, will my traffic be split between the two, or is the second gateway I add only used if the first one goes down?

Thanks

Comment: More information about the equipment is required to answer this question.  Unless the gateway in question has automatic load balancing as a feature its not going to balance to load between the the two gateways.

Comment: You also have to be aware that some apps will have an issue if traffic leaves by one gateway and returns by a difeerent one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I understand it, the second default gateway will only be used if the first one is unavailable.

EDIT: A second gateway may also provide a route to a network that is unavailable via the first, in which case that one will be used instead.